# UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height not working using Xcode 7/Swift 2, Target iOS7

Tags: ios7, ios8, swift2, xcode7, uiscreen

In the past when I've used Xcode 6.4, I have been able to adjust things like font sizes, etc. based on device sizes.  This was for my apps that were targeted at iOS 7. Now for Xcode 7 and Swift 2 it only allows for this with iOS 8 and newer. It prompts me to fix it with 3 different option. I can't get any of the choices to work.  Is there a way to adjust things for different devices in Xcode 7 using Swift 2 for older iOS 7 devices?

In Xcode 6.4, It would look like this in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 1334.0 {
    //Name Details
        redLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
        yellowLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
        greenLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
        blueLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
}
```

In Xcode 7 and Swift 2, it gives me an alert `'nativeBounds' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer`.  It then prompts to fix it with 3 different possible fixes:

1) If I choose `Fix-it Add 'if available' version check` it does this:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeBounds.height == 1136.0 {
            //Name Details
            redKid.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
            yellowKid.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
            greenKid.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
            blueKid.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 13)
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

2) If I choose `Fix-it Add @available attribute to enclosing instance method` it does this:

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
override func viewDidLoad()
```

3) If I choose `Fix-it Add @available attribute to enclosing class` it does this:

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

How can I fix this and have it run a target of iOS7 and adjust for different device screen sizes?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found that I can use `let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` in the `viewDidLoad()`.  I then can set `font` and other items based on `bounds.size.height`.  So an example would be:

```
if bounds.size.height == 568.0 { // 4" Screen
    redLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 15)
} else if bounds.size.height == 667.0 { // 4.7" Screen
    redLabel.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 18)
}
```

To find the `bounds.size.height` for each device, I did a `print(bounds.size.height)` on my `viewDidLoad()`.

I can specify for the two different devices and add more, like the iPhone 6 Plus and iPad Retina as well. Worked when I set the `iOS Deployment Target` to iOS 7.0.

Comment: From Apple Docs: "In iOS 8 and later, a screen’s bounds property takes the interface orientation of the screen into account". But my knowledge doesn't extend (yet) as to how to become "always aware". Maybe through the AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, use the **bounds** and **scale** properties of a UIScreen object to understand how UIKit present the display to your app, and the **nativeBounds** and **nativeScale** when you need to work with the exact number of pixels on the display.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html